# GCov and GCC, *.da Files Not Created

Tags: gcov

I am using GCC version 3.3.6.  When I instrument my object files with `-fprofile-arcs` and `-ftest-coverage`, the appropriate `*.bb` and `*.bbg` files are created.

The object files are then linked together into a static library `libfoo.a` with:
`ar rcs libfoo.a foo1.o foo2.o`.

Finally, a series of static libraries are linked together to create my executable with:
`gcc -fprofile-arcs -o foo.o <static libraries linked all>`

Now, when I run the image, the *.da files are not getting created.  Is there a step that I am missing?  Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The executable needs to be linked with the gcov library:

```
gcc -fprofile-arcs -o foo.o <static libraries linked all> -lgcov
```

**EDIT**: Starting from gcc 4.1.2, the `--coverage` option can be used as a synonym for `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` (when compiling) and `-lgcov` (when linking).

Also, it is worth noting the files are created in the same directory as the compilation. This directory shall be reachable from the execution environment. Recent versions of gcc (4-1) introduced environment variables to tune the target directory : GCOV_PREFIX and GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP, see the [cross-profiling section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Cross_002dprofiling.html#Cross_002dprofiling) of gcc doc.